# Gitlab CI/CD: pass job environment variables to shell script

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have like this job in my gitlab ci cd configuration file:

```
jobName:
  stage: dev
  script:
    - export
    - env
    - sshpass -p $SSH_PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_LOGIN 'bash -s' < script.sh
  when: manual
```

I tried share/pass current job env vars to my custom bash script file by adding this command in my job:

```
- export
- env
```

But my jon can't access (don't see) to job env vars. How I can correctly share job all env vars to bash script?

Answer (score 2):

I believe [`dotenv`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) might be suitable for this.

```
job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
        - export VAR=123
        - echo $VAR
        - echo "VAR=$VAR" > variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env

job2:
  stage: stage2
  script: 
        - echo $VAR
```

And your VAR should be available in downstream jobs.